# initialization: address of static symbol 'myStruct' is used for symbol 'otherStruct'

Tags: c, static, warnings

The following code is giving me the warning:

> > initialization: address of static symbol 'myStruct' is used for symbol 'otherStruct'

The warning is given at the closing bracket/semicolon of the initialization of SomeOtherStruct otherStruct.

```
typedef struct
{
    U32BIT memberA;
    U32BIT memberB;
} MyStruct;

typedef struct
{
    U32BIT *memberAPtr;
    U32BIT *memberBPtr;
} SomeOtherStruct;

static MyStruct myStruct;

int main(void)
{
    SomeOtherStruct otherStruct =
    {
        &myStruct.memberA,
        &myStruct.memberB
    }; // <<-- warning given here.

    // doing something with otherStruct
}
```

If I make `SomeOtherStruct otherStruct` `static` then the problem goes away. But I prefer not to do that because I don't want `SomeOtherStruct otherStruct` to always be in the memory as it is passed to another function/file where it will be stored.

(SomeOtherStruct is coming from a library which requires it to be initialized with a list of pointers.)

Why is my compiler giving me this warning, what can I do about it or what am I doing wrong? Because I don't see any problems at all with this code (and neither is QAC/MISRA-C because normally QAC/MISRA-C is complaining).

Also, might be worth nothing, my compiler is FUJITSU Softune Fs907s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do a web search for:

> "initialization: address of static symbol" "is used for symbol"

You will find this:

http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/MICRO/fma/pdfmcu/softccmp-cm25-00202-2e.pdf

Which is apparently the manual for the very same compiler you say you're using.  The relevant passage says:

```
W1020C %Z: address of static symbol `%D' is used for symbol `%D'
```

> The address of a static variable is used as an initial
>   value. It is possible to change the value of the static variable from
>   the outside of the compile unit. Continues the compilation making the
>   initialization valid.

So that's exactly what you've got here: legal C, but your compiler is warning you.  Why it feels this particular thing is worth warning about, I'm not sure, but hopefully from here you can figure out how to either avoid the warning, or disable it.

Comment: still doesn't make sense why I can still do `MyStruct *myStructptr = &myStruct;` (within main(){}) because that does not give a warning.

Also, thanks for the link to manual, I searched google for said search but couldnd find anything.

Comment: Also doing: `SomeOtherStruct otherStruct; otherStruct.memberAPtr = &myStruct.memberA;` doesn't give a warning either which seems to same construction though.

Comment: (what is the time-out on editing comments?). Anyway, solved the issue by making the `otherStruct` variable static and passing a pointer to said library and altered the library to accept said pointer and not having a full-blown copy of `MyOtherStruct`, but just the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This Warning is to avoid exposure of *internal Linkage*. Word `static` on global variable will make variable with internal linkage, which means internal to the compilation unit.